# Why does a telnet to port 80 seem to hit a different server than Firefox?

Tags: http

I'm new to low-level HTTP stuff and am not sure what to make of what I am seeing.

If I go to a particular internet web server (let's call it www.someserver.com for now... I'll give the real one if it's really needed), Firefox happily pulls up its home page. If, however, I do a

```
telnet www.someserver.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.0
```

...what I get returned appears to be the Apache default "It works" page. Trying to GET another page on the server that Firefox will happily pull up receives a 404 from telnet. It's like they're hitting different servers, but these requests are both coming from the same machine, so I'm not sure how.

What could cause such behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be serving different sites based on the host header sent by the browser. Your telnet connection wouldn't send that header unless you explicitly typed it.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308163

Comment: Do you know of any way to see exactly what Firefox is sending in its requests?

Comment: @glibdud Download and install Live HTTP headers, it's a firefox add-on.

Comment: @Nacereddine Thanks, using that for some more debugging now.

Comment: @glibdud and if you want more control about what is sent use [Tamper data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/)

Comment: @BNL Perfect, that was it. If I send the Host header that Firefox sends, I get what I expected in the telnet session. Thanks, and also thanks to Nac (and Timster above).